# how to get rid of ChromiumOS

Tags: chromeos

I tried to install ChromiumOS in Ubuntu, didnt work out, and now when I do

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up lightdm-login-chromiumos (1.0) ...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     6    0     6    0     0     26      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    26
Downloading: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_ChromiumOS/287303/chrome-linux.zip
ZIP: /tmp/fileMlTJZc.zip
Warning: Illegal date format for -z, --timecond (and not a file name). 
Warning: Disabling time condition. See curl_getdate(3) for valid date syntax.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127  100   127    0     0    238      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   237
Archive:  /tmp/fileMlTJZc.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/fileMlTJZc.zip or
        /tmp/fileMlTJZc.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/fileMlTJZc.zip.ZIP, period.
dpkg: error processing package lightdm-login-chromiumos (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm-login-chromiumos
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

how to get rid of it?

Comment: maybe use `sudo apt-get purge chromiumos`?

Comment: unable to locate chromiumos

Comment: retry with other names like _lightdm-login-chromiumos_

Comment: thanks, it worked, whats the difference between remove and purge?

Comment: purge is removing also dependency packages, wich aren't used anymore.

Comment: remove - remove packages, purge  - remove packages and config files
source: sudo apt-get --help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove it using

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-login-chromiumos
```